# Will AWS Auto scaling create EC2 with my application which is already deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have one EC2 which has few application deployed in IIS, when i try to auto scale it creates an instance but those application are not deployed in newly created instance.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it should... you need to give more information in order for us to troubleshoot why it doesn't. but it's really not stack overflow question

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do? If not, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are generally three ways you would bootstrap your instances in autoscaling group:

- Write [User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html) script that would run at instance creation time and install, setup and run your application when the instance is launched.
- Create [custom AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html) containing your application and use that AMI in your ASG's launch template/configuration.
- Deploy your application to the instances through [CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html). This will also allow you to re-deploy new versions of it easily.